# Assign position number to chars in R

Tags: r

I have a file which contains 10^3 characters. My file looks like:

```
ATTGC
CTGGC
TTTGC
GCTCT
```

I want a file which have all these character in a row with position like as follows:

```
1 A
2 T
3 T
4 G
5 C
6 C
7 T
```

till end.
I tried by vi command line but didn't get result for large file. Is this possible in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the below solution, replacing `InputPath` with the path to your .txt file:

```
# Read input
input <- read.delim("InputPath", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[,1]

# Split each element into single characters and combine
output <- unlist(strsplit(x = input, split = ""))

# Save output
write.table(x = output, file = "output.csv", sep = ",", col.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# create input file
cat("ATTGC
CTGGC
TTTGC
GCTCT",file="test.txt")

# check input
file.edit("test.txt")

# read
txt <- scan(file="test.txt",what=character())
# [1] "ATTGC" "CTGGC" "TTTGC" "GCTCT"

# build output
df <- data.frame(X =unlist(strsplit(txt,"")))
#    X
# 1  A
# 2  T
# 3  T
# 4  G
# 5  C
# 6  C

# write output
write.table(df,"test2.txt",quote = FALSE,col.names = FALSE)

# check result
file.edit("test2.txt")

# clean up
unlink(c("test.txt","test2.txt"))
```